# How do I share same variable between independent functions

Tags: php, function

How do I share same variable between independent functions? I don't want to use globals and at the moment, I'm not using OO. This example only works within nested functions:

```
$example = function() use ($id){
                    echo 'id is: ' . $id;
                };
```

Is there a way to access (read: to call) that nested function from a different function? I could then return $id.

Main issue: I'm retrieving an ID from a database and I want the moderator to be able to edit material based on the ID that is being retrieved from the database.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but nested function in your example. by any chance you meant anonymous function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment , I'm not 100% what exactly you mean by independent and nested function but here is PHP's manual on (anonymous function)[http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php].

Anyway I have put a sample together  assuming you are really meaning nested functions

```
<?php

function wrapperOne($id) {

    $newId = function($id) {
        return $id * 2;
    };

    return $newId($id);
}


function wrapperTwo($id) {

    $doSomething = function() use(&$id) {
        $id *= 3;
    };

    $doSomething();

    return $id;
}

echo wrapperOne(2); // 4;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo wrapperTwo(2); // 6;
```

Comment: Yes, I meant anonymous functions that are being nested in another function. Your examples should do it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use passing by reference read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
function changeMyID(&$id)
{
    $id = 1;
}
function printMyID($id)
{ 
    echo $id;
}

$id = 2;
changeMyID($id);
printMyID($id); // this will output 1;
```